# BUILD_NUMBER changes to number from dsl.groovy to jenkins job

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy

In our git repo when updated and when dsl.groovy exists, it will create a Jenkins job if it doesn't exists. If it exists, it will overwrite it with whatever we have in dsl.groovy.

I have this code in the dsl.groovy

```
shell('echo "BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}" > log.txt')
```

However, when the Jenkins job gets created, it's wrong. It parses the variable name rather than pasting the original code in Execute shell. Here is a screenshot of the jenkins job specifically the Execute shell. https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8f6a.jpg

What am I doing wrong? I really need the value of the BUILD_NUMBER in my unix shell since I use the number as part of directory name that I will create with mkdir (ie. mkdir project_acme_${BUILD_NUMBER} )

Comment: Is your process using [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to seed new jobs?

Comment: i'm not sure how are devops team is doing it. But I just learned something. If I use a different variable name, it looks great in web ui. It doesn't get parsed. So why is ${BUILD_NUMBER} being parsed?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the shell command using the "execute" method seems to work for me.

```
"echo BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER} > log.txt".execute()
```